# Use AJAX result only after page was loaded

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I run a `$.get()` call as soon as JS is executed, this is before the `$(document).ready()` is triggered. How can I use the result of the `$.get` as soon as `$(document).ready()` was triggered? I don't want to send the `$.get()` after `$(document).ready()` was triggered.

---

**Solution:** As Jonathan Julian mentioned I came across this solution:

```
$.get('my_script.php', function(data) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // I can use data here as soon as document is available! 
    // No flickering of the updated div! :)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `success` handler, do what you need to do in a `$(document).ready()` function. It will either run right away, or wait until the document is ready.

Answer (score 2):

the page will render and fire document ready as soon as it can, you can't delay it and would have no reason to, whatever ur thinking there is a better way to do it

Comment: My $.get is called __before__ document ready! I don't want to delay the document.ready, but I want to hook into it with the already prepared result from $.get.

Comment: yeah but because it's asynchronous you have no guarantee of when it's going to finish. I'm not sure what it is you're getting with `get()` but whatever it is should be sent with the first page load, I have no idea why you would need to do 2 http requests before the page is ready..

Comment: Maybe the data is not available during page rendering. There is nothing wrong with @powtac's approach.

Comment: let's say for the sake of argument that this data was somehow only available after the first http request had been made, I still don't get why you would need to delay document ready, it's ready when it's ready, surely whatever data it is you can insert it into the DOM anyway you like

Comment: The $.get, is fired way earlier than the document.ready, and normaly the result returns also before document.ready.

Comment: well if it does great, I just dont get why another http request is needed, if you think you can help me understand better then please do

Comment: For techical reasons I do the AJAX request, If I would have the information ready before sending the page to the user I would of course add the required data there!

Comment: yeah, I get that, what is it that's not ready? do you pull info from a database? an external service? what requires waiting? And why can it not just be added to the page when it arrives? I don't see why you would ever need to delay the on ready event

Comment: @Tules I think you are confused about how the `ready` event works. Every function bound to the `ready` event is run immediately as soon as the document is loaded and ready; if a fn is bound to `ready` and the document is _already_ "ready", it is run immediately.

Comment: sorry what was it that I said that made it seem that I didnt know that fact? I realize what the ready event is but what I'm saying is he could fire a get request and then insert it into the DOM whenever it arrives, I dont get why that MUST be done before `ready`

Comment: in fact "the page will render and fire document ready as soon as it can" was THE FIRST thing I said in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable in global scope and use to store value from get(). You can use it later anywhere anytime.

Comment: It's hard to define "later" in an event-driven thing like a browser. That var might get accessed before the ajax request is complete.